# How to sort items by array size in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 3 millions items with this structure:

```
{
    "id": "some_id",
    "title": "some_title",
    "photos": [
        {...},
        {...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Some items may have empty `photos` field:

```
{
    "id": "some_id",
    "title": "some_title",
    "photos": []
}
```

I want to sort by the number of photos to result in elements without photos were at the end of the list.

I have the one working solution but it's very slow on 3 million items:

```
GET myitems/_search
{
   "filter": {
      ...some filters...
   },
   "sort": [
      {
          "_script": {
              "script": "_source.photos.size()",
              "type": "number",
              "order": "desc"
          }
      }
   ]
}
```

This query executes 55 seconds. How to optimize this query?

Comment: Is it an option to just store the array size in a seperate field?

Comment: Yeah, that might be the only option ^^.

Comment: @Bertvan, this will cause the reindexation :(

Comment: There's a way without re-indexing all data :-)

Comment: Adding a field does not cause reindex: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, adding a new field with the number of photos would be the way to go. There's a way to achieve this **without reindexing** all your data by using the [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery).

Basically, after installing the plugin, you can run the following query and all your documents will get that new field. However, make sure that your indexing process also populates that new field in the new documents:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myitems/_update_by_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.nb_photos = ctx._source.photos.size();"
}'
```

After this has run, you'll be able to sort your results simply with:

```
"sort": {"nb_photos": "desc"}
```

Note: for this plugin to work, one needs to have [scripting enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting), it is already the case for you since you were able to use a sort script, but I'm just mentioning this for completeness' sake.

Comment: This will work on data that will not change. If new records are added to elastic, they will not have a correct value. When combined with an approach that will calculate the data before insert, then it's capable of handling new data as well.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that he should make sure that `... the indexing process also populates that new field in the new documents`;-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved with Transform directive. Now I have a mapping:

```
PUT /myitems/_mapping/lol
{
    "lol" : {
        "transform": {
            "lang": "groovy",
            "script": "ctx._source['has_photos'] = ctx._source['photos'].size() > 0"
        },
        "properties" : {
            ... fields ...
            "photos" : {"type": "object"},
            "has_photos": {"type": "boolean"}
            ... fields ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can sort items by photos existence:

```
GET /test/_search
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "has_photos": {
               "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this will cause full reindexation.

Comment: If you just want to have the documents with 0 photos at the end, you can also do 2 queries (perhaps multiquery) where you use a match_all filter on photos for the first and not(match_all) for the second.