# Sort query by length of field in Elstic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a field in each of my documents like so

```
'some_field': 3, 5, 10
```

But each document could have a very length of numbers,

```
'some_field': 3, 5, 10        # Doc 1
'some_field': 5               # Doc 2
'some_field': 3, 5, 10, 20, 9 # Doc 3
```

Is there a way to query and sort by the length so that my results would be arranged as so:

```
'some_field': 3, 5, 10, 20, 9 # Doc 3
'some_field': 3, 5, 10        # Doc 1
'some_field': 5               # Doc 2
```

My current query, sorting by _id at the moment

```
es_object.search(index='index', size=500, body={
            "sort": [
                {"_id": "desc"}
            ],
            "query": {

            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "some_field"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": [],
                "should": [],
                "must_not": []
            }
        }})
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33250652/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do script sort

```
{
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "script": "doc['some_field'].value.length()",
            "type": "number",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    "query": {

        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "some_field"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    }
}
```